# Free Client side Library for connecting to Red5 server in iOS

Tags: ios, client-side, rtmp, red5

I am developing audio video application in iOS that will stream videos and audio using rtmp and for teh application I am using Red5 server. I am unable to find a free client side library for connecting to Red5 server. Can anyone suggest free client side library to connect my application to Red5 server for audio and video streaming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For connection with Red5 you can use RTMP connection and for this

you can use client side rtmp library

Best RTMP library for iOS available at : https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos

Comment: I have read its documentation. It doesn't specify what all servers does it support. Does this lib support connection to Red5 server?

Comment: have you check this ? http://blog.themidnightcoders.com/index.php/2011/06/29/rtmp-communication-library-for-ios-is-available/

Comment: Yes, I have checked the above link. It doesn't support Red5 for Media Library. The communication Library supports red5. As I said I wanna build a video and audio streaming app I do need something to work for audio n video streaming. Any other option?

Comment: Then Adobe Air for mobile is best option...

Comment: you have to pay 5k for the MediaLib license

Comment: yes,I tried the demo version of the library

Answer (score 1):

I integrated the same. But once I come to know that its license is of $5k, I researched for other open source and found the following:-

https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore

It works great for RTMP Red 5 server in my case

Comment: ...can you let me know if you made it work with Red 5 because I could not made it work with Adobe Media server and I don't know how to use Red 5 server

Comment: ..I am trying to make the video core work with Red5 server 1.0.4 and its trying to connect and getting disconnected. What is the cocoapod version you used for videocore and version of the red5???